# Xcode Core Data Editor stopped working in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode12

does anybody have the same problem, that you can not edit the core data anymore?
Even if I start a new project in Xcode 12 or in the latest beta it just looks like this:
[image]

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: What's the "can't edit" part? I see there seems to be something in front of your window, but apart from that, are you saying you can't click the Add Entity button at the bottom?

Comment: I can but I can’t see what’s happening.

Comment: Well, there's something in front of the window. I don't know what it is.

Comment: That's what the editor looks like. Can you edit your question to describe how, specifically, it is not working for you? What action(s) did you take, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: @TomHarrington See how there's a big black rectangle blocking most of the editor window? That's the OP's issue. You can just make out how it covers part of the Plus button at the bottom. We should see a bunch of interface there, not a black blank.

Comment: Yes, but this black rectangle stays there even if i move or resize the window. no matter if i use xcode 12 or the latest xcode 12 beta

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. Seems to be a bug as a few more experiencing it here.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved in the Beta 10 of Mac OS Big Sur

Answer (score 1):

**Temporary solution:**

To see the Attributes:
**Change** the **Editor Style** ([On the bottom right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn8YR.png)) from *'Table'* to *'Graph'*.

You can then select entity, add attributes or **edit attributes in the 'Inspector'** ([Button on the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IAc1.png)).

Comment: this is not working for me, i see the entities but not the attributes :(

Comment: Try in this order: (1) Change editor style to 'Graph'. (2) Open the inspector. (3) Add a new entity. (4) Select the new entity in the graph editor. (5) Add a new attribute. (6) Select the new attribute inside the entity. (7) Edit the attributes in the inspector. **Good luck :)**

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to Bug Sur and was resolved in **Big Sur Beta Version 10**.

Just update your OS to fix this problem.